# Why is os.remove None after executing pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7

I create a LazyLoader class which downloads files from S3 to the local file system, but only if they were not downloaded before. This class deletes the stuff it downloaded once it gets destroyed:

```
def __del__(self):
    """Remove downloaded files when this object is deleted."""
    for downloaded_file in self.loaded_data.values():
        os.remove(downloaded_file)
```

The tests pass, but after pytest tells me that the tests passed I get:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method LazyLoader.__del__ of LazyLoader({})>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_lazy_loader.py", line 47, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Line 47 is `os.remove(downloaded_file)`. So `os.remove is None` evaluates to `True`. Why? How can I fix that?

If I move the code in `__del__` to a method `clean()`, I don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**del**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

> '**del**()' can be executed during interpreter shutdown. **As a consequence, the global variables it needs to access (including other modules) may already have been deleted or set to None**. Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the **del**() method is called.

Comment: Even if I let the global object name start with an underscore, I still get that error. I thought that this might be the issue, so within `__del__` I tried to `import os`. Still I get the same error.

Comment: As written in the docs, when your `__del__` is being called it might be that os.remove is `None`. So dont do this cleanup in `__del__`. Use unit test hooks like tear down.

Comment: Well, it is not only about the unit tests. Not even mainly, because the unit tests are executed in a container which is afterwards deleted. It is about the main application ... Thinking about it, in my current case, the problem is not too big, because also that is deleted after every re-deploy.

Answer (score 0):

- If it's just unit tests, use [`tearDown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) method.
- If the problem occurs when running your application and you want to do a cleanup at the end of the program, consider using [`atexit.register`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/atexit.html#atexit.register).
- You might also use [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module for temporary files automatically removed when closed.
- If your use-case allows that, turn `LazyLoader` into a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).

If none of the above applies, simply call `clean()` explicitly. It will follow *explicit is better than implicit* rule.